# KNeighborsRegressor User-Defined Metric Reshaped

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, nearest-neighbor

I am defining a custom distance metric for use in a KNearestRegressor from Scikit-Learn.

My distance metric takes two images and computes their similarities based on visual features:

```
def imageMatchingMetric(x,y): 
      # the RGB images have size 480x640
      x = x.reshape(480,640,3)
      y = y.reshape(480,640,3)
      (...)
```

Thus, my X matrix is a matrix of images. Then I call

```
metricObject = sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.get_metric('pyfunc', func=imageMatchingMetric)
clf = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=d['kneighbours'], metric=metricObject)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

and I receive the error from `imageMatchingMetric` that when reshaping, I must keep the sizes to be the same.

I found out from debugging that the `x` `imageMatchingMetric` receives is a vector of length 10 which is not a row from `X`.

Why is that? And how can I fix that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap your metric inside a DistanceMetric object, you can just pass it as an argument to KNeighborsRegressor.

Then since you're doing a reshape, it's going to fail because sklearn tries to check if your metric is a valid function [1] by trying to call it with two vectors of shape 10 or so. You can just detect that case and return 0 (which is a valid distance metric).

[1] https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/969337c905bc4b83d43105fd807576bc2efea536/sklearn/neighbors/dist_metrics.pyx#L1091

Comment: Thank you for your time taken resolving this problem, I really appreciate it! :)